# How to add a Behaviour to a Control in my Xaml but only for a specific platform?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

I have created a behaviour for my Xamarin application but I only want this behaviour to be used when running on UWP. How can I do this in XAML?

I know about using `OnPlatform`, But I am not sure how to use something like that for Behaviours and Effects. (Or generally anything that is a list in XAML).

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean Styles for example Buttons platform-specific

Comment: Not sure I interpreted that sentence right, but I mean I have an ImageButton in my XAML, and I want the ImageButton.Effects to be Platform dependent. That is I want to have some Effects working on iOS and Android but not on UWP. Does that clarify?

Comment: [Platform Differences with OnPlatform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/essential-xaml-syntax#platform-differences-with-onplatform) works through one OnPlatform code example (but not for behavior/effect). If you don't see how to apply that to your case, then **show the behavior/effect code you want to make one platform.** E.g. "I can get this code to work on all platforms", then I tried to modify it like this ..., but it gave this ... warning in Output pane and did nothing ... **Always show some code;** much easier to give you good help!

Comment: I delete the answer , misread the question

Answer (score 1):

You just could check in your OnAttachedOn method of your behaviour which device it is like so:

```
if(Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.UWP)
{
    //then do something
}
```

This is a good example how behaviours work: https://github.com/codemillmatt/xamarin-show-demos/blob/master/Behaviors/Behaviors/Behaviors/EntryPressCommandBehavior.cs